# Where in Ireland was Handy Dugan born and baptised?

Tags: baptism-records, ireland, 1810s

Handy Dugan appears in the 1851 England and Wales Census at West Bromwich, Staffordshire, England with his birth recorded as Ireland about 1816 and a wife named Mary:

> "England and Wales Census, 1851," database with images, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:SGGZ-V5F : 29 July 2017),
>   Handy Dugan, , Staffordshire, England; citing , Staffordshire,
>   England, p. 48, from "1851 England, Scotland and Wales census,"
>   database and images, findmypast (http://www.findmypast.com : n.d.);
>   citing PRO HO 107, The National Archives of the UK, Kew, Surrey.

How can I locate a more accurate birth/baptism date and place for him?

Comment: as well as immigration to USA if that was done.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than for "any information" about a range of records.  I will [edit] your question to try and provide that focus to keep it open.

Comment: What makes you think he immigrated to the USA?  In any event, seeking evidence for that should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

He also seems to be appear in the index to the 1861 census on FamilySearch as "[Andrew Duggan](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M78J-Y3S)", This might suggest a transcription error, but **double check on the original image**. The following screenshot is from [FreeCen](https://www.freecen.org.uk/):

[image: 1861]

---

I checked [FreeBMD](https://www.freebmd.org.uk/cgi/search.pl), and found a death record for an Andrew Duggan in West West Bromwich in 1865. This is just before ages were added to the indexes, so this might not be the same man. However, if you are interested, the details are:

- Quarter: March 1865;
- District: W Bromwich;
- Volume: 6b;
- Page: 457

---

It may be possible to find Handy/Andrew Duggan in Ireland by tracing his children.

The Duggans have four children listed in the 1851 census who were also born in Ireland: Mary (born c1840), Margaret (born c1842), Anthony (born c1844) and Thomas (born c1847). [Note that "Anthony" may be transcribed as "Andrew" in the 1861 census]. The children were all born before civil registration was introduced in Ireland, so you will need to search church records.

The first thing to do is to check the **original** census images. Transcription errors are not uncommon when online indexes are created for censuses, and you want to make sure that you are searching for the correct names! You'll probably need to access these via a subscription service like [Ancestry](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/) or [Findmypast](https://www.findmypast.co.uk/). If you are not already a subscriber, your local library may offer access.

Once you have confirmed the names of the children, a good starting point is [FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/search), which has a good collection of church records from Ireland. Another place to try is the [Church Records](https://churchrecords.irishgenealogy.ie/churchrecords/) on the Irish Genealogy website. Both sites are free. If you are unsuccessful there, you'll need to check the Irish parish register collections on the subscription sites.

Comment: The new GRO index gives an age of 49 for that death which would give a birth around 1816 so that does seem likely.

Answer (score 1):

A candidate for your Handy Dugan may be Andreas Duggan who was baptised 31 May 1816 at Killea, Waterford, Ireland to parents Matthai Duggan and Catharina Power.

Another candidate may be Andrew Duggan who married Mary Cassin in Feb 1839 at Raheen, Laois, Ireland.

I found both candidates in the Ireland, Catholic Parish Registers, 1655-1915 of Ancestry.com.